# Implementing IEqualityComparer

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5, hashcode, iequalitycomparer

I've added to my class the `IEqualityComparer` implementation, not sure if the code bellow is the correct one, especially the `Equals(object x, object y)` functions: should we `override` or make a `new` implementation of the Equals method, like this: ?

```
public class PropertySettings : IEqualityComparer
{
    public int? Precision { get; set; }
    public double? Min { get; set; }
    public double? Max { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || !(obj is PropertySettings))
            return false;

        var ps = obj as PropertySettings;

        return
            ps.Precision == this.Precision &&
            ps.Min == this.Min &&
            ps.Max == this.Max;
    }

    public bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        if (x != null && x is PropertySettings)
            return x.Equals(y);
        else
            return object.Equals(x, y);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(Precision, Min, Max);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return 0;
        if (obj is PropertySettings)
            return (obj as PropertySettings).GetHashCode();
        else
            return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Neither, as there's no parent method to hide or override. `public bool Equals(object x, object y)` will do.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen false, as `object.Equals(x, y);`

Comment: That's `Object.Equals` -- the method is static. There is no point in adding a `new` method to your type with this signature since it will never be called.

Comment: @JeroenMostert the static method can't be distinguished from the non static one in a child declaration, you will have the warning at least (see updated OP)

Comment: Ah, hang on -- you are implementing `IEqualityComparer`. That makes no sense, you need `IEquatable<PropertySettings>`. Even better is avoiding all of this if possible and make your class a `record`, where you get all of this for free -- `record PropertySettings(int? Precision, double? Min, double? Max)`. That version is immutable, but that's arguably a good thing as well (and you can redeclare the properties if you really want mutability).

Comment: If, on the other hand, you're really looking to implement some sort of custom logic for equality comparison that can be applied to different properties of different types, you need a completely different approach -- one that doesn't involve comparing the properties of your *own* object at all. In that case you need to scrap your current class and start over and sketch out an intended scenario first, since that's more complicated. Even then you would probably want to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` and not `IEqualityComparer`, since non-generic collections are rare these days.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I think record seems OK to me, I don't have a custom logic. However, is the Equals code itself OK as for you as in OP?

Comment: @JeroenMostert The code is actually in .NET 5, not .NET 6, so can't use records

Comment: Records are part of C# 9, which is supported in .NET 5. Only if you're on Framework or early versions of Core would you not have access to records.

Comment: @serge if you want to implement the default equality logic for `PropertySettings`, you implemented the wrong interface. `IEqualityComparer` is mean for *custom comparer* classes, eg `StringComparer` which specifies `IEqualityComparer` instances that use different kinds of comparisions, eg case-insensitive or sensitive, culture-specific or invariant. If you want to specify the default equality for `PropertySettings` you need to implement `IEquatable<>` instead. Comparers can only be used in methods that actually accept a comparer parameter

Comment: @serge eg, when you create a `Dictionary<string,x>` string's default equality is used. If you want to create a case-*in*sensitive dictionary, you need to use the [Dictionary<TKey,TValue>(IEqualityComparer<TKey>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-dictionary-2-ctor(system-collections-generic-iequalitycomparer((-0)))) constructor and pass eg [StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.invariantcultureignorecase?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

According to the `IEqualityComparer` code example provided by microsoft, you will want to use the new keyword (so hiding the Equals implementation of the object) for implementing Equals.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.iequalitycomparer.equals?view=net-6.0#system-collections-iequalitycomparer-equals(system-object-system-object)

As pointed out by [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert)
below, these can be incorrect. His recommendation of implementing `IEqualityComparer.Equals` works as well. You can also use `override`. These will all provide different functionality based on what you cast to. Here is a brief explanation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords

Basically, using `override` would mean that you will use your .Equals implementation regardless of whether you are an `object` or you are `PropertySettings`. If you use `new` when you are an object you will use the base `.Equals(...` functionality (that of `object` in this case). If you explicitly implement `IEqualityComparer.Equals(...` then you will use the `.Equals` when you cast your object as an `IEqualityComparer`. This leaves you with the choice of how you are using your class.

Comment: The examples aren't always right, and in this case I'd very much argue against the choice the author made there. It's far cleaner to implement the interface explicitly instead (`bool IEqualityComparer.Equals(...)`, `int IEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(...)`), precisely to prevent confusion with the `Object` methods. That is, assuming you have to implement `IEqualityComparer` at all these days, which is not probable.